# cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not invoking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

On UIView Class adding `UIViewController` which have `UITableView` class now UIView Class is added to on another UIViewController class

```
//MyControllerView
//added filterSideView side to it and adding JaffaViewController.view 
-(void)loadControllerJaffa
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    JaffaViewController *jaffaViewController =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JaffaViewController"];
    jaffaViewController.view.frame = filterSideView.bounds;
    [filterSideView addSubview:jaffaViewController.view];
    [jaffaViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface JaffaViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *jaffaTableView;

@end
```

Implementation Class

```
@implementation JaffaViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _colorNameList = [[ColorModelClass colorListNames]allKeys];
    _jaffaTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _jaffaTableView.dataSource = self;
    _jaffaTableView.delegate = self;
    [_jaffaTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    _jaffaTableView.dataSource = self;
    _jaffaTableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Welcome";
    return cell;


}
```

Issue is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not invoke at all.
I have set datasource and delegate methods both.

It's invoking the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` both method's but not `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.
Current I am using Xcode 8.3 & iOS 10.3 version.
Your kind input will help me to solve the issue.

Comment: If numberOfRows or Sections are zero. It won't revoke. Check numberOfRows

Comment: Make sure delegate method set properly. That's the most important. I knew that you have done all these things. But I'm asking you to just make sure.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I trice check the datasource and delegate method.

Comment: @Kiran Have you set a breakpoint and tested.

Comment: This problem seems like due to calling of a class in which tableview method is written. Have you try to set the delegate and DataSource in ViewDidAppear method. Please try it and let me know if you get any sucess.

Comment: tableView.datasoure = self;   tableView.delegate = self;  And then check numberofrows delegate

Comment: According to her numberofrows and numberofsection are working.So that's not the issue.

Comment: Might be an issue with JaffaViewController object. Check if the object is retained or not.

Comment: You should make sure that your tableview is visible and size is not zero

Comment: I set size zero  for tableview footer,  Its good for unwanted rows removed,  sir my issue is with cellforrowindexpath method not invoking even after setting delegate and datasource method.

Comment: check `filterSideView` height it should be greater than zero.

Comment: @SandeepP :) yes its greater then zero. (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 200, height = 460))

Comment: Call `reloadData`?

Comment: @Larme [jaffatableView reloadDate]; i call still not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Code

```
-(void)loadControllerView {
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                     bundle:nil];
    JaffaViewController *jaffaViewController =
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JaffaViewController"];

    [jaffaViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    jaffaViewController.view.frame = filterSideView.bounds;
    [filterSideView addSubview:jaffaViewController.view];
    [jaffaViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**Notes:**

Make sure you have confirm datasource and delegate for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set datasource twice? Remove code in viewDidAppear and add `[_jaffaTableView reloadData];` at the end of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

```
tingViewController *destVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RatingViewController_id"];


destVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString* string)
{
    NSLog(@"Returned strng.....%@",string);
};

destVC.productId = self.productId;

[destVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self addChildViewController:destVC];
[self.view addSubview:destVC.view];
[destVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [destVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}];
```